# Can i automatically send SMS (Without the user need to approve)

Tags: android, android-activity, sms

I'm rather new to Android. 
Im trying to send SMS from Android application. 
When using the SMS Intent the SMS window opens and the user needs to approve the SMS and send it.

Is there a way to automatically send the SMS without the user confirming it?

Thanks,
Lior

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can  use this method to send an sms. If the sms is greater than 160 character then sendMultipartTextMessage is used.

```
private void sendSms(String phonenumber,String message, boolean isBinary)
{
    SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERED), 0);

    if(isBinary)
    {
            byte[] data = new byte[message.length()];

            for(int index=0; index<message.length() && index < MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH; ++index)
            {
                    data[index] = (byte)message.charAt(index);
            }

            manager.sendDataMessage(phonenumber, null, (short) SMS_PORT, data,piSend, piDelivered);
    }
    else
    {
            int length = message.length();

            if(length > MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH)
            {
                    ArrayList<String> messagelist = manager.divideMessage(message);

                    manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null, messagelist, null, null);
            }
            else
            {
                    manager.sendTextMessage(phonenumber, null, message, piSend, piDelivered);
            }
    }
}
```

### Update

piSend and piDelivered are Pending Intent They can trigger a broadcast when the method finish sending an SMS

Here is sample code for broadcast receiver

```
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String message = null;

            switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                message = "Message sent!";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                message = "Error. Message not sent.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                message = "Error: No service.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                message = "Error: Null PDU.";
                break;
            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                message = "Error: Radio off.";
                break;
            }

            AppMsg.makeText(SendMessagesWindow.this, message,
                    AppMsg.STYLE_CONFIRM).setLayoutGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM)
                    .show();
      }
  };
```

and you can register it using below line in your Activity

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));  // SMS_SENT is a constant
```

Also don't forget to unregister broadcast in onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: In a dual sim phone, the sim card to send message is selected for the user in dual sim settings ( android general settings ) in preferred sim settings. Is possible select what sim uses to send sms (Programmatic) ?

Comment: @AndrésRicardoTorresMartínez Dual sim is not supported by Android. It is supported by device manufactures who wrote their own API's for supporting dual sim. So please consult the device manufactures for this.

Comment: How to check if the message was successfully sent? Once the text is sent, will it show up on my text messaging app? Also, what if I want to send to multiple phone numbers?

Comment: So call `sendSMS` function and right below that add `registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));` from `main`? What do you mean by`SMS_SENT` is constant? Can I also do a recursion, that if the message fails to send, to retry every hour? Thank you :)

Comment: Yes call sendSMS function and right below that add registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT)); If you want to send SMS every hour you can use `AlaramManager` class. You can call this method any number of times :) .  SMS_SENT  mean it is just a constant like `private static final String SMS_SENT = "my.app";`.

Comment: hi can you please tell me how do i send sms when accelerometer detect a fall

Comment: @Sunny After sending sms i am not getting broadcat even i have already register it. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @Sunny Sorry for distrubing! i have registered receiver via LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context). It was wrong. Your example is working on. Thanks

Comment: @Sunny Awesome Answer but what is `SMS_PORT` thanks :)

Comment: what is the value of MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH 140 or 160 ?

Comment: How quickly will I get the confirmation of the msg sent? I have where the user can retry the msg and I have to check whether the msg was delivered or not?

Comment: you can wait until that broadcast finish. It may take a second or so may be less.

Answer (score 19):

If your application has in the AndroidManifest.xml the following permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

you can send as many SMS as you want with

```
SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
manager.sendTextMessage(...);
```

and that is all.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can send SMS using the [`SmsManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html). Please keep in mind that your application will need the [`SEND_SMS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#SEND_SMS) permission for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can send sms without making user interaction...But it works, when user wants to send sms only to a single number.

```
try {    
    SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(RecipientNumber, null,    
    "Hello SMS!", null, null);    
} catch (Exception e) {    
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new    
    AlertDialog.Builder(this);    
    AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();    
    dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());    
    dialog.show();    
}
```

Also, add manifest permission....

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```