# Sending SMS programmatically without opening message app

Tags: android, android-activity

So far I am using the following code to send SMS to another phone through my app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "sms:" + srcNumber)); 
                    intent.putExtra( "sms_body", message ); 
                    startActivity(intent);
```

However, this opens up the native messaging app, thereby putting my app's activity in the background. Is it possible to send the SMS *directly* without the native messaging app opening up? If yes, how?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620150/can-i-automatically-send-sms-without-the-user-need-to-approve)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send SMS in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967448/send-sms-in-android)

Comment: That doesn't explicitly mention the underlying issue of native messaging app opening up, though I agree both solutions are mentioned. This might be a useful material to those who require direct SMS sending approach, since I have explicitly highlighted the differences in the result obtained using the two approaches.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

You can send messages from your application through this:

```java
public void sendSMS(String phoneNo, String msg) {
    try {      
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, msg, null, null);    
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ex.getMessage().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Also, you need to give `SEND_SMS` permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` to send a message

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />`

Comment: Yea.. I figured this out. Thanks for the prompt reply though :)

Comment: You can appect this answer and close this thread if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Its not letting me do so yet :) I have to wait :)

Comment: does this require the user to approve before sending message

Comment: This only works for builds where the API target is older than 23.  For newer builds, you need to jump through more hoops as Google changed how permissions work for "dangerous" permissions like SEND_SMS.  Sigh.

Comment: Does this also add the sent message to the default sms app (i.e. system database)?

Comment: Please note that if you are publishing your app on google play this is a Policy violation and will get your app suspended eventually.

Comment: @MIKEPERETZ Can you link to any official documentation that says it's a policy violation? I tried searching for it but I don't find anything to support that.

Comment: tust me you won't find any information. google are very discrete in details about specifics if you read their policies. everything is broad. practically speaking i recommend every developer reading this: [link](https://www.medianama.com/2015/01/223-google-play-mistakes-app-suspension/)

Comment: @MIKEPERETZ is right, Please see this https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/. I received a mail for using SMS related permissions in app.

Comment: @All It's an old answer and currently it's violation of Google Play Policy so kindly don't use above code.

Comment: As of now accessing call log or sms is considered a policy violation without prompting the user for making your app as default sms/call log handler

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal    So what's the official way if want to add to feature to my app without violation of policy

Answer (score 22):

```
public void sendLongSMS() {
    String phoneNumber = "0123456789";
    String message = "Hello World! Now we are going to demonstrate " + 
        "how to send a message with more than 160 characters from your Android application.";
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message); 
    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
}
```

and don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: No one has mentioned this very important concept of multi-parts sms messages for the limitation of a sms message, when it contains single-byte or multibyte-byte characters. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 14):

Sending sms with permission request :

Add In manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Add Java Function :

```
void sendSmsMsgFnc(String mblNumVar, String smsMsgVar)
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        try
        {
            SmsManager smsMgrVar = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsMgrVar.sendTextMessage(mblNumVar, null, smsMsgVar, null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Sent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch (Exception ErrVar)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ErrVar.getMessage().toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ErrVar.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS}, 10);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This will ignore the first message until the user grants permission (or many messages will be ignored until permission grant)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, found the answer to my own question :)

Use the following code for the same :

```
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                     sms.sendTextMessage(srcNumber, null, message, null, null);
```

This requires the following permission to be declared on the android manifest xml.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, sms, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

`SmsManager.getDefault()` now deprecated. Use `getSystemService()` instead.

In Kotlin you can do it like this:

```
fun sendSMS(context: Context, phoneNumber: String, message: String): Boolean {
    return try {
        val smsManager = context.getSystemService(SmsManager::class.java)
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null)
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        false
    }
}
```

And don't forget to add this to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo;9677498416, null, sms, null, null);

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).