# Launch a different sms app to send sms programmatically without opening it

Tags: android, sms

**This below approach opens the app but doesn't do anything.**

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String phoneNumber = "phone number here";
            String text = "Hi belated happy diwali";


            Intent smsIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("sun.way2sms.hyd.com");
            smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            smsIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", text);
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311243/sending-sms-programmatically-without-opening-message-app

Comment: it works with default sms app, but i want third party sms app

Comment: What does that mean? You want to use a third-party app without opening it? Please clarify exactly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, like default SMS Manager you can't send message directly with other apps....like way2sms / whatsapp. If and only if they are providing there SDK and with that option.

Do you know the 'key' -> "address" and "sms_body" are using by way2sms app to receive your data!!!!

For Eg: Facebook you can post directly with ur app by using some user permissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party app the best you can do is launch the third party app with the data pre filled just like the native app.

If the third party app provides any support for sending sms in the background (like a broadcast or something) then you can do it. Although the chances of any app having such functionality is low