# Android: How to include phone number on Intent.createChooser activity for native SMS option

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile, sms

I'm trying to implement sending an SMS from an Android app with a predefined text message. I'm using the native chooser activity by doing:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

String[] phoneNumber = {selectedContact.getPhoneNumber()};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.contact_message_body));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber);

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Message"));
```

The phone number is indeed stored in the phoneNumber variable, but when testing it, it's not being passed over to the recipient field for the Messages option. So the EXTRA_TEXT info fills the new SMS but the recipient is empty.

I've seen others use **Intent.ACTION_SEND** but this will not work in my case, because I also have to implement Email sending from the same chooser.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311243/sending-sms-programmatically-without-opening-message-app

Answer (score -2):

Did you try to use SmsManager I think it's more easy to use

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not looking for an alternate way of sending the SMS. I want to use the intent.createChooser activity, since it expands beyond SMS to other apps such as Mail or Whatsapp.