# Any way to send text message without getting a confirmation?

Tags: android

Is there any way to send a text message without getting a confirmation? My current code for this is:

```
String phoneNumber = "1234567";
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));  // This ensures only SMS apps respond
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "TESTING TEXT MESSAGE! IT WORKS!");
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean with "confirmation"?

Comment: have you try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311243/sending-sms-programmatically-without-opening-message-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you should use `SmsManager`. Here is an example:

```
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNo", null, "sms message", null, null);
```