# How to post data to my web server using mobile SMS without internet?

Tags: android, twilio-api

I am developing an android application in which the device's current location is posted to my Web API after every 3 seconds using internet. My web api is hosted on server. Without internet, location updates won't be posted to the server.

What I want is that, when internet is not available on the mobile device,  want to send location using sms.

I looked into twilio. But I couldn't find a good tutorial on how to use it in android and how to send sms to a URL.

How do I post data to my server using sms without internet?

Comment: For the Android part, you only need to send SMS. Have you tried searching for that?

Comment: Yes I did. I couldn't find anything

Comment: I can't imagine how you searched because it took me ~8 seconds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311243/sending-sms-programmatically-without-opening-message-app

Comment: Sms Manager sends SMS to another phone number. I want to send sms to  a URL

Comment: you can't send SMS to URL, SMS can be sent only to a phone number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The internet connectivity problem can be solved in the following way.

When internet is not available on your user's device, send an SMS which contains location coordinates and user name to a second mobile device in which internet is available. Then that second device will parse the incoming SMS, extract coordinates and username and will send it to the server.