# getting back to my application after sending sms using intent android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using intent to send sms .

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phoneNumber));
 intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
 intent.putExtra("sms_body", messageBody);
 intent.putExtra("exit_on_sent", true);
 startActivityForResult(intent, 6789);
```

1. How can I make it ***return to my application*** with result? Currently it stays in "messages" view.
2. is there any Broadcast Receiver to know if the sms  has been sent or delivered ?

Comment: There is no WAY .. You can not handle behavior of a third party app .,

Comment: thanks for your input ....  is there any alternate way to know if the sms has been sent  or delivered without taking the SMS permisssion  ???

Comment: You could send the sms yourself ... see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311243/sending-sms-programmatically-without-opening-message-app

Comment: @RajeevRanjan you can't check the status of sms without permission. And Google updated policy for sms permissions . Read it https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/reminder-smscall-log-policy-changes.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29

Comment: @Rajasekaran  as per google policy we can not take the sms permission until.it meets certain conditions... my app doesn't fall under this policy thats why i have to switch to intent ... i don't want to loose my current functionality...