# How to send sms without waiting for the user to press "send"

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to send an sms using intent i am able to send the phone number 
and the text to send but after running the line
startActivity(smsIntent); the problem is the user have to press the "send" button.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620150/can-i-automatically-send-sms-without-the-user-need-to-approve/7620220#7620220

Comment: i dont understand what are the values of SMS_SENT,SMS_PORT,MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH,SMS_DELIVERED

Comment: see the comments there.

Comment: if piSend and piDelivered are Pending Intent then why are they only used when length < MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH?

Comment: after reading the comments besides SMS_SENT there are no explanations for the other values(i dont understand SMS_SENT too why it needs to be my.app?).

Comment: SMS_SENT and SMS_RECEIVED are constant for e.g.`final String SMS_SENT= "sms_sent"`

Comment: it does not need to be my.app you can put anything here

Comment: ok and what about piSend and piDelivered why are they only used when the message length is smaller then the MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH?

Comment: MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 160 piSend and piDelivered are already explained there.

Comment: i understand  piSend and piDelivered are used in a normal case but why not when we call  manager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phonenumber, null, messagelist, null, null);?

Comment: you can call, but you will not get notify when sms has been sent.

Comment: thank you in the end youre solution worked

Comment: Glad it works. Please upvote if it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Send it directly using `SmsManager`. This will require the `SEND_SMS` permission.

If you delegate the work to a third-party app (e.g., via `ACTION_SEND` or `ACTION_SENDTO`), then the user and the other app decide if and when to send the SMS, not you. You are merely suggesting an SMS to send.

Comment: SmsManager does not work for me and from what i understand it does not show the sms at the inbox of the end device

Comment: @adi181188: `SmsManager` is what SMS clients on Android use.

Comment: if i delegate the work to a third-party app(i use ACTION_SEND) is there a way to to send it and not only create it?. like suggesting to actually send

Comment: @adi181188: No.